# Fatal error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "a". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am having the following error:

> Fatal error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "a". Use
>   mongoose.model(name, schema)

Here is my file structure:

--------a.model.js--------

```
'use strict';
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var A = new Schema({
 name:String,
 });
 module.exports = mongoose.model('A', A);
```

--------b.model.js-------

```
 'use strict';
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var a = require('../a/a.model');
 var B = new Schema({
 aid: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"a"},
 name:String
 });
 module.exports = mongoose.model('B', B);
```

--------queryfile.js---------

```
 exports.all = function(req, res){
   b.find().populate("aid").exec(function (err, b) {
   if(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return handleError(res, err);
  }
  return res.status(200).json(b);
 });
}
```

---

I have been trying to call `populate` but every time I am getting the above error, I tried to put `{}` condition in `find({})`. Tried to put conditions which are always true but every time the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try changing:

`aid: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"a"},`

to

`aid: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"A"},`

I think it is case sensitive, and you are declaring your model as:

`module.exports = mongoose.model('A', A);`